# HQL query for multiple types/classes

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, types, hql

I have a complex class hierarchy with multiple levels of inheritance, and I need to query for certain specific types within that hierarchy, using HQL.

Let's say I have classes Cat, Dog and Monkey, with a common base-class Animal.

How do I write a query that selects only some of those, let's say, Cat and Dog?

I also need to sort or filter by certain Animal properties - so let's say, animals with Sex="Male" and order by Name.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard JPQL function is `TYPE()`, that supported in Hibernate as well, as mentioned in its [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-entity-type-exp).

Please, follow an example:

```
select a from Animal a
where type(a) in ('Cat', 'Dog')
    and a.sex = 'Male'
order by a.name
```

Hibernate also uses the `.class` implicit property:

```
select a from Animal a
where a.class in ('Cat', 'Dog')
    and a.sex = 'Male'
order by a.name
```

Comment: according to the [NH knol](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-12-hql-the-hibernate-query-language) by Fabio Maulo, "the special property class accesses the discriminator value of an instance in the case of polymorphic persistence. A Java class name embedded in the where clause will be translated to its discriminator value." - so it looks like that's supported. I'll try it out tomorrow morning and post the result here, thanks!

Comment: The magical .class property works great with HQL in NH! As a warning, the Criteria API is not quite as helpful - it needed a horrible work-around, manually retrieving the discriminator from the mapping, as the Criteria API does not translate class-names to discriminator values, but expects you to know the discriminator value in advance. Terrible stuff. But with HQL it works great!